# Add active class by default to the first element from class list and change active class on click next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm a newbie in react. I have two class in css file. One is btn and another is active. I want to set an active class to the first button by default and when I click on other buttons it'll be remove and add to the current button. I'll be thankful if anyone help me about this. Thanks in advance.

Here is my codes

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Tab = () => {

  const [tabBtn, setTabBtn] = useState(false);

  const handleBtn = () => {
    setTabBtn(true);
  }

  return (
    <div className='btnContainer'>
      <button className={"btn" + (tabBtn ? " active" : "")} onClick={handleBtn}>One</button>
      <button className='btn'>Two</button>
      <button className='btn'>Three</button>
      <button className='btn'>Four</button>
      <button className='btn'>Five</button>
      <button className='btn'>Six</button>
      <button className='btn'>Seven</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Tab;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's make a few optimizations here:
First let's put an array of all your buttons and then use state to track which one is selected.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const buttonList = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];
const Tab = () => {

  const [tabBtn, setTabBtn] = useState('One');

  return (
    <div className='btnContainer'>
{
  buttonList.map(b => {return (
  <button 
    className={b === tabBtn ? 'active' : '' }
    key={`${b}Button`}
    onClick={() => setTabBtn(b)}
  >
    {b}
  </button>)}
)} 
    </div>
  );
}

export default Tab;
```

Without map

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Tab = () => {

  const [tabBtn, setTabBtn] = useState('One');

  return (
    <div className='btnContainer'>

<button 
    className={'One' === tabBtn ? 'active' : '' }
    key={`One Button`}
    onClick={() => setTabBtn('One')}
  >
    One
  </button>
<button 
    className={'Two' === tabBtn ? 'active' : '' }
    key={`Two Button`}
    onClick={() => setTabBtn('Two')}
  >
  Two
  </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Tab;
```

Obviously, add in the rest of the buttons up to 7.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me how can i achieve this function without map method.

Comment: Updated without the use of map. I highly recommend map, as it reduces the amount of re-used code. Also highly recommend the use of the key prop to improve the speed of updates in your render tree.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I'm looking some shortcut methods. Is there any shortcut way to achieve this, like map method have. Hope you'll get my question. thank you

Comment: I provided a solution with map and without map. Either one works. Not sure if I understand the question.

Comment: $(".btn").on("click", function() {
    $(".btn").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

I'm trying to achieve this function in react without map method and also shorter syntax. Hope this time I can clear the problem. Thank you

Comment: Why would you mix javascript and react like that? Let react control your state and application of classNames. When you shortcut react using raw javascript like that, you've bypassed all the advantages of maintaining a virtual DOM and having react as your source of truth. I do not recommend your proposed solution.

Comment: Sorry. actually I'm not trying to use jquery. I'm telling you that in normal html with the help of jquery I can do this. But how can I do this in react? Without the map mehtod (your second method ) which is actually not good optimized. I need a shorter syntax like you wrote with the map method (your first method).

Comment: There are ways to do this using refs in react, but the question is why? You're using react, which in this sense, is declarative. You're using imperative programming methods in a declarative context. Map is encouraged for use in react's documentation and they even provide keys so that unnecessary re-renders are prohibited. There may be some overhead, but then why are you using a framework beyond jQuery. Docs using map for this use case and showing keys optimizing re-renders: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: yeah, you're right. I got it. Many many thanks for your time and support. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Use this code :

```js
className={`btn ${tabBtn ? " active" : ""}`}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I wrote the same code. I want to set active class to the first button by default. After that when I'll click on other buttons, active class will be remove and add to the current btn. Thanks